# How to launch Java with options -X from a shell script

Tags: java, shell, sh

I want to create a script (foo.sh) such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -o posix
. setpath.sh
java foo.Bar "$@"
```

and I want to use like:

```
./foo.sh -p -o -ff filename
```

but the shell returns an error message. illegal option

if I launch

```
java foo.Bar -p -o -ff filename
```

then it works.

How can create a script for that?

I guess

```
. setpath.sh
```

has problem..

If I change it to

```
. setpath.sh --
```

then

```
./foo.sh -anyoptoptions
```

works...

but I have quite no idea what happens...

Comment: why not use `java foo.Bar -p -o -ff filename` inside the script, where filename is the input you can accept?

Comment: other options also vary.

Comment: does changing script to `export Param1=$1
export Param2=$2
export Param3=$3
export Param4=$4
java foo.Bar Param1 Param2 Param3 Param4` work for you?

Comment: It doesnot work, the same error illegal option comes.  and one thing i realize ... I modified the question please see it

Comment: What does `. setpath.sh` actually do? It sounds like it is doing something to the value of `$@`. What does `printf '%s\n' "$@"` show after calling `setpath.sh`, and does it agree with how you called `foo.sh` in the first place?

Comment: Actually, is the error coming from `setpath.sh`? `. setpath.sh` has the same positional arguments as the shell that calls it, while `. setpath.sh --` has only one argument, `--`.

Comment: Thank you. ```setpath.sh``` should not have any arguments. Without ```--```, the error comes from ```setpath.sh``` because it has option but options for ```foo.sh```.  If there are same characters, .... it is also problem though.   Using ```--``` is common? If so and only the one is read by ```setpath.sh```, I am happy.